# How do I add a class name to body tag if module position has a module?

Tags: php, html, css, joomla

I'm trying to add a class to the body tag if a particular module position has at least 1 module in it. I tried adding some code to add the class to the body tag, but on page load (with the code added) the page is blank. My code is below.

```
<body class="site 

<?php
if ($this->countModules('nav-productpage')) :
    echo 'productnav'
endif;
?>">
```

Comment: You are missing a semicolon... So 500 fatal error => blank page

Comment: :) A second pair of eyes always helps. Thanks Brewal! It now works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got a blank page because of a missing semicolon causing syntax error. You could check your console and see the 500 error status.

```
<body class="site 

<?php
if ($this->countModules('nav-productpage')) :
    echo 'productnav'; // missing semicolon here
endif;
?>">
```

The code could be reduced to :

```
<body class="site<?php echo $this->countModules('nav-productpage')) ? ' productnav' : '' ?>">
```

Comment: I was just about to suggest the reduced version, makes it a lot more readable

Comment: Thank's guys. It works great. I just switched to the reduced version.